# WiX Installer: Error 1921 on Service Installation

Tags: windows, service, wix, installation

I have a Windows service (among other things) that I am installing during the process of my WiX Installer. The installer was working great, but it started to have issues at one point. I believe (*not 100% on if I did it before or after the errors happened*) I had manually removed the service due to the uninstaller not actually removing files (*I refreshed my GUIDs and they started to work*).

On install now, it begins the process and hits a wall. Sits there for a minute, and then throws out the error

> Service '' () could not be stopped.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to stop system services.

To confirm, my service name is not mentioned above, it is actually just `''`

I've turned on verbose logs, and can see that the error is `1921`.

Around that 1921 error, there are a handful of `I/O on thread 5068 could not be cancelled. Error: 1168` errors.

It seems to copy all the files where they should be before it hits the error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the a mismatch in the naming of my ServiceInstall to my ServiceControl. Once I ensured the two were matching (I was loading an empty reference for my ServiceControl, hence the '') the service was fixed.